# Randomize the letters in the middle of the word, while keeping the first and last letters unchanged

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Cutuk
 */
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a;
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        a = in.nextLine();
        char first = a.charAt(0);
        System.out.print(first);
        int v= a.length()-1;
        char last = a.charAt(v);

        int k= a.length();
        int random=0;
        char x='\u0000';
        char middle= '\u0000' ;

        for (int i=1; i<a.length()-1;i++){
            random= (int )(Math.random() * (k-2) + 1);
            middle=a.charAt(random);
            x=middle;
            System.out.print(x);
        }            
        System.out.print(last);
    }
}
```

I am supposed to take a word, shuffle the letters inside, but keep the first and the last letter unchanged. I managed to randomize, but I cannot keep it from repeating.

Comment: "keep it from repeating": what does this mean?

Comment: Please use meaningful names for your variables, you give us a hard time to analyze your code otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect: when you pick middle letters at random, it is impossible to guarantee that all letters from the middle of the word would be printed (and as a consequence, that other letters would not be repeated).

There are several ways of fixing this:

1. Each time you generate a random index, mark that index in an array of `boolean`s. The length of the array is equal to the length of the word. Check the array before using each new index that you generate; if the index is marked, continue generating new random indexes until you hit an empty one.
2. Create an array of integer indexes of letters inside the word (i.e. 1 through length-1, inclusive). Do a [random shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on the array, and use the shuffled indexes to pick middle letters.
3. Similar to 2, except you put all middle letters in an array, and shuffle it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I would suggest you start by building a [`List<Character>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and then use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and finally build your return `String` with a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like

```
private static String shuffleLetters(String in) {
    if (in == null || in.length() < 3) {
        return in;
    }
    char first = in.charAt(0);
    char last = in.charAt(in.length() - 1);
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char ch : in.substring(1, in.length() - 1).toCharArray()) {
        chars.add(ch);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(chars);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(first);
    for (char ch : chars) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    sb.append(last);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a `List<Integer>` for storing the random numbers that you generated.

Here is your code from above, cleaned up, with meaningful naming and the `List` for looking up the history:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final List<Integer> rndHistory = new LinkedList<>();   // <-- your history

        System.out.print("Please type a word: ");
        final String input = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print(input.charAt(0));
        for (int i = 1, random = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
            do {
                random = rnd.nextInt(input.length() - 2) + 1;
            } while (rndHistory.contains(random));       // check the history

            rndHistory.add(random);                      // add to the history
            System.out.print(input.charAt(random));
        }
        System.out.println(input.charAt(input.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Main differences:

- `final Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());` Using
  the [the java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class is a better way for generating
  random numbers.
- `final List<Integer> rndHistory = new LinkedList<>();` This is the actual difference, part of the mechanism to prevent double shuffles
- `System.out.print("Please type a word: ");` a meaningful prompt for
  the user (who is going to know what to do, when you program is
  executed and there is nothing on the screen?)

and finally:

```
do {
    random = rnd.nextInt(input.length() - 2) + 1;
} while (rndHistory.contains(random));       // check the history

rndHistory.add(random);                      // add to the history
```

The 'prevent a random number from being used twice' mechanics

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "shuffling" can allow a middle character to sometimes be swapped with itself, you can do something like:

```
private static final String[] TEST_WORDS = {"apple", "banana", "pear", "raspberry", "cucumber", "watermelon", "a", "ab", "", null};

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for (String word: TEST_WORDS)
    {
        System.out.println(shuffleInside(word));
    }
}

private static String shuffleInside(String word)
{
    String ret = word;

    if (word != null)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int strLen = word.length();

        if (strLen > 2)
        {
            char[] middleChars = word.substring(1, strLen - 1).toCharArray();
            shuffle(middleChars, r);
            ret = word.charAt(0) + new String(middleChars) + word.charAt(strLen - 1);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private static void shuffle(char[] chars, Random r)
{
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
      char c = chars[index];
      chars[index] = chars[i];
      chars[i] = c;
    }
}
```

Which handles the case where the word is null, one character, two characters, or two or more characters and produces the following output on a single run:

```
apple
bnaana
paer
rerrsbpay
cbuemucr
waomteerln
a
ab

null
```

Answer (score -1):

For your random try this: Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());